# Phone Data Annotation .Net Core 1.1 not validating

Tags: validation, razor, data-annotations, asp.net-core-1.1

I think the [Phone] annotation should be applying a standard regex pattern to the UI input field but I am finding that I can enter anything words, all manner of special characters and no validation errors occur.

Below is the HTML and then Model entry

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Supplier.Phone)</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Supplier.Phone, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Phone" })
    <span asp-validation-for="Supplier.Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
 </div>

[Required]
[Phone]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

All other validations such as [EmailAddress], [Range] and [Required] are working just fine.

I did come across this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727074/email-data-annotation-validation-works-but-phone-doesnt) suggesting the HTML5 did not support phone, is that still correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to use regex for that.
e.g.

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The Phone Number field must contain only numbers")]
```

or

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
```

The first one will allow only numeric values while second one will allow formats like 0123456789, 012-345-6789, (012)-345-6789 etc.